# Maven: cannot find symbol (for a method declaration)

Tags: java, maven

When I attempt to run my implementation file in Maven, I get the following error:
`cannot find symbol`. I clearly imported (and wrote the corresponding method) and here's the weird part: Intellisense recognizes that I wrote the method (and even suggests it) but Maven does not.

Here is the implementation file, specifically how I imported the said function and how I called the methods I wrote:

```java
//the root of the problem
@Component
public class service_impl implements service {

    @Autowired
    private QuantityRepository quantityRepository;

    
    private Collection<quantityUpdateResponse> updateQuantity(Collection<someArgument> quantityUpdateRequests, int id_value) {

            Map<Integer, Quantity> inputValue = ...

            Map<Integer, quantityGroup> allocationIdsToUpdatedQuantities = quantityRepository.updateQuantity(inputValue, id_value); // <--- This works fine! (I didn't write this)
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = quantityRepository.quantityChangeDetector(inputValue, id_value);                    // <-- However, this doesn't. I am confused as to why that is. (I wrote this)

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------work----------------------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String message = "id_value: " + list.get(i).get(0) + "\n Existing Value: " + list.get(i).get(1) + "\n New Value: " + list.get(i).get(2);
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(message);
            }
            return updateResponses;
        }
    }
}


// This is the interface of the method that I'm trying to call
public interface QuantityRepository {
    Map<Integer, quantityGroup> allocationIdsToUpdatedQuantities(Map<Integer, Quantity> inputValue, int id_value);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quantityChangeDetector(Map<Integer, Quantity> inputValue, int id_value);
}

//This is the method I'm trying to call 
@Component
public class quantityRepositoryImpl implements QuantityRepository {
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quantityChangeDetector(Map<Integer, AllocationQuantity> inputValue, int id_value) {
        return anotherObject.anotherMethod(inputValue, id_value); //this returns an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> but the problem does not originate here
    }
    
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, quantityGroup> updateQuantity(Map<Integer, Quantity> inputValue, int id_value) {
        return doesSomeStuff;
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. (I included some comments [on the part of the code that says "the root of the problem"] that highlight the part where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Is that all in a single file? What can't find the symbol?

Comment: No, these are not in one same file. When I perform a "mvn compile", Maven returns the error "cannot find symbol." HOWEVER, intellij's intellisense recognizes the method that I created. That's where the point of confusion is. I performed a mvn clean and even tried reloading/invalidating the cache on Intellij to no avail.